# Как устранить ошибку "Данный хост не известен"?

Tags: delphi

При использование компонента `ServerSocket` выводится ошибка:

> "Данный хост не известен"

Какой хост нужно писать (например, для чата)?

Comment: А вы, простите, какой пишете? ))) 

К какому хотите подключиться, тот и надо указывать.

Comment: Что нарпример?

Пишу  localhost или свой ай-пи - выдаёт эту ошибку.

Comment: @romanzi, Приведите пример проблемного кода.

Comment: Ошибку пишет уже после компиляции.

Comment: Так Вы все таки дайте весь ваш исходный код, я у себя его проверю.

Comment: А сервер-то запущен? Порт указываете в клиенте тот же, который слушает сервер?

Comment: По идее текст ошибки говорит не о том, что сервер не запущен, а о том, что хост в принципе не возможно найти. Наверняка товарищ делает что-то не то: пишет хост не туда или порт пихает в хост.. что-нибудь в таком духе.

Comment: Ну в принципе да.